# "Вопрос закрыт"

Tags: обсуждение, вопросы, причины-закрытия

Мой не так давно заданный вопрос [Верстка интерактивной карты](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/613944/) был закрыт "по причине того, что необходимо переформулировать вопрос так, чтобы можно было дать объективно верный ответ".

Я сам решил этот вопрос и хотел даже написать на него ответ но увидел, что его закрыли.

Все решалось очень легко и объективно верный ответ можно было дать. К тому же этим вопросом интересовался не я один (что можно понять по оценкам).

Нормально ли закрывать такие вопросы? Вопросы по программированию ведь не всегда состоят именно в коде.

Comment: Понимаю ваше возмущение, но тут так принято, если для ответа по делу надо будет много писать (и возможно спорить)

Comment: Я не возмущен и вопрос был задан достаточно давно. Просто хочу понять - идти с такими вопросами на стек или куда подальше)

Comment: Всегда есть шанс, что кто-то даст ответ раньше, чем вопрос закроют.

Comment: @avp кстати ответ не такой бы и большой получился бы, кмк.

Comment: Можно попробовать переоткрыть %)  Но тут как минное поле - никогда не знаешь, когда подорвешься))

Comment: Попробовал улучшить вопрос. Добавьте больше описания к требованиям и поведению, т.к. сейчас вопрос слишком общий, и подойдет даже подмена всей картинки с растеризованым текстом. Т.к. подобные "широкости" как раз таки отнимают возможность дать объективно верный ответ и порождают ярмарку споров "что лучше".

Comment: @АлексейШиманский правильно! Переоткрыть и закрыть снова, на этот раз как слишком общий :-)

Comment: Переоткрыли. Нормальный вопрос, вроде.

Comment: Инициировал новое закрытие. Ответы - супер :)

Comment: @Visman Всегда найдутся люди, которые пытаются самоутвердится. Я на вас не обращаю внимания

Comment: @Visman Инициируйте новое закрытие, я буду инициировать новое открытие. Среди ответов там появился ответ от Алексей Шиманский, который соответствует всем канонам. Вам все ещё не нравятся ответы или Вы таки пытаетесь самоутвердиться за счет того, что можете инициировать закрытие?

Comment: @РашенБеар, сравните время моего комментария и его ответа. + закрываются не ответы, а кривые вопросы.